# Show $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, universal-property

Let $G$ be a group such that there is a homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ and such that for every group $H$ and every homomorphism $\phi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to H$ there is exactly one homomorphism $\xi\colon G\to H$ such that $\xi\circ f=\phi$.

Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

I think that this is rather very easy though I can't see it ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take $H$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$, and $\phi$ to be the identity...

Comment: Then I get that $f$ is injective, but why is it onto?

Comment: a non trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You should post essential information in the question, rather than leave it title only. I've edited to fix the problem.

Comment: Calling the homomorphism $g:G\to \mathbb{Z}$ obtained from Steve D's  suggestion (i.e. the one such that $gf=1_\mathbb{Z}$) note that both $1_G$ and  $fg$ are homomorphisms such that $(fg) f =f$ and $1_g f=f$ and hence $fg=1_G$.

Comment: In case you are interested this is standard categorical fact about initial objects in coslice categories.

Comment: Thank you, you removed the veil from eyes! @Nex: If you change your comment to an answer, i'd be glad to accept it